# install memcache onfedora linux OS

Tags: apache, memcached

I installed memcache in the following way:

1) yum install memcached
2) yum install php-pecl-memcached
3) Also enabled the  'memcached.so' in php.ini

I tested the memcached in the follwing way:

$mc = new Memcache;
$mc->addServer('localhost', 11211);
echo "Server's version: " . $mc->getVersion() ;

But it generates the following error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: undefined symbol: php_json_encode in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcache' not found in /root/memcacheTest.php on line 2

Thank u.

Comment: Voting to close: Off-topic: This question belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP well (or at all), but from the error message I'll hazzard a guess that you do not have the PHP JSON extension installed, which is apparently needed by the memchached extension.

[Apparently](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php), the JSON extension has been in PHP since version 5.2.0, therefore:

- You have an older version and you need to upgrade or install the JSON extension yourself

or

- Your operating system distributor supplies the PHP JSON extension in a different package that you have not installed.

There is of course the possibility of a misconfiguration, but I think it's slightly less likely.

Answer (score 1):

This showed memcached.so didn't loaded successfully.

**Error shows the reason: json.so should be load before memcached.so**

Please use `php -m | grep memcached` to check whether memcached.so is loaded successfully.

- If show `memcached`, this mean it succeeded.
- If show like `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: undefined symbol: php_json_decode_ex in Unknown on line 0`

Here is the solusion:
e.g your php.ini is /etc/php.ini, your php.d is /etc/php.d/

**Solution 1**

1. comment 'memcached.so' in php.ini
2. `vim /etc/php.d/memcached.ini`
3. add `extension=memcached.so` in /memcached.ini
4. `php -m | grep memcached` check whether memcached is succeed loaded

**Solution 2**

1. `rm /etc/php.d/json.ini`
2. add `extension=json.so` in php.in before `extension=memcached.so`
3. `php -m | grep memcached` check whether memcached is succeed loaded

Answer (score 0):

Can you check and double check user permissions? Additionally, my experience with PHP is that the distribution repository versions of PHP aren't very good. I solved those symbol errors by compiling PHP from the ground up. But that's a very radical and time-consuming solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=17574&edit=1

> Just make sure that extension=json.so is specified BEFORE
>   extension=memcached.so.
>
> I had placed extension=memcached.so in php.ini, and extension=json.so
>   was specified in /etc/php.d/json.ini, that is parsed AFTER php.ini.
>   That is why PHP can't find php_json_encode() at the point of loading
>   memcached.so.

Also, check that the permissions on memcached.so are the same as the other extensions

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the version 2.0. It helped for me.

```
yum -y install gcc-c++
wget http://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/0.50/+download/libmemcached-0.50.tar.gz
tar xzf libmemcached-0.50.tar.gz 
cd libmemcached-0.50
./configure 
make 
make install
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcached-2.0.0b2.tgz
pecl install memcached-2.0.0b2.tgz
echo 'extension=memcached.so' > /etc/php.d/memcached.ini
service php-fpm restart
cd ..
rm -r libmemcached-0.50*
rm -r memcached-
```